# Getting Theme Roller Config JSON in APEX

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm trying to get Current Theme configuration JSON from `apex_application_theme_styles` table, `theme_roller_config` CLOB column, and use it in JavaScript function.

The code I'm using is implemented as follows:

- `pr_get_theme_config` in `Processing` > `Ajax Callback`

```sql
declare
  c_trc_json clob;
  c_trc_json_vars clob;
begin
  select theme_roller_config into c_trc_json from apex_application_theme_styles where application_id = :APP_ID and upper(IS_CURRENT) like upper('Yes');
  apex_json.parse(c_trc_json);
  --dbms_output.put_line(apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'vars')); -- for debugging purposes, but prints nothing
end;
```

- `getThemeConfig` function in `Page` > `JavaScript` > `Function ... Declaration`

```
function getThemeConfig() {
  var themeConfig = new htmldb_Get(null, &APP_ID., 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=pr_get_theme_config', &APP_PAGE_ID.);
  var themeConfigJson = themeConfig.get();
  return themeConfigJson;
}
```

Upon calling, `getThemeConfig` returns empty string, but should return JSON.

For better understanding, here's an example of what could be inside `theme_roller_config` (after every `\n` is replaced with real new line)

```
{
  "customCSS": "/* custom CSS, should be discarded in this case, cause could contain a large multiline CSS code block */",
  "vars": {
    "@g_Accent-BG": "#008328",
    "@g_Link-Base": "#267373",
    "@g_Header-BG": "#007228",
    "@g_Accent-OG": "#fafafa",
    "@g_Header-FG": "#ddffdd",
    "@g_Region-BG": "#ffffff",
    "@g_Region-Header-BG": "#007228",
    "@g_Nav-BG": "#ffffff",
    "@g_Nav-Active-BG": "#aaaaaa",
    "@g_Actions-Col-BG": "#ebebeb",
    "@g_Body-Title-BG": "#ffffff",
    "@l_Left-Col-BG": "#ebebeb",
    "@g_Nav-FG": "#dddddd",
    "@g_Nav-Active-FG": "#ffffff",
    "@g_Button-BorderRadius": "4px",
    "@g_Form-BorderRadius": "4px",
    "@g_Body-Content-Max-Width": "auto",
    "@g_Focus": "#007228",
    "@g_Form-Item-BG": "#fefefe",
    "@g_Nav-Icon": "#1c1c1f",
    "@menu_Tabs-Active-Text": "#0a6a14",
    "@g_Container-BorderRadius": "4px",
    "@g_Body-BG": "#f0f0f0",
    "@l_Button-Primary-BG": "#fd8b43",
    "@l_Button-Danger-BG": "#e53835",
    "@l_Button-Warning-Text": "#a30b0b",
    "@l_Button-Success-BG": "#007228",
    "@l_Button-Success-Text": "#ffffff",
    "@g_Form-Item-FG": "#3e3e3e",
    "@l_Button-Primary-Text": "#5f3100"
  }
}
```

And now, main questions:

- How to look at results of `apex_json.parse` procedure while debugging my PL/SQL in IDE (in my case, it's `PL/SQL Developer`)?
- How to access `vars` property of JSON in PL/SQL and pass it to JavaScript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to get an object from `vars` property is to use `apex_json.write` and `apex_json.g_values` in PL/SQL AJAX Callback Process and call it from JS with `apex.server.process`. Here's an example:

- `pr_get_theme_config` in `Processing` > `Ajax Callback`:

```sql
declare
  c_trc clob;
begin
  select theme_roller_config 
    into c_trc 
    from apex_application_theme_styles 
    where application_id = :APP_ID 
      and upper(IS_CURRENT) like upper('Yes');
  apex_json.parse(c_trc);
  apex_json.write(apex_json.g_values, 'vars');
end;
```

- `Page` > `JavaScript` > `Function ... Declaration`:

```
apex.server.process(
  'pr_get_theme_config',{},{
    success: function (data) {
      doSomething(JSON.parse(data));
    },
    dataType: 'text'}
);
```

Working with `apex.server.process` bear in mind that IE11 does not support Promises, so you should use `success` property for a callback. Otherwise you can use `.then()` in other browsers.

More docs:

1. [APEX API Reference - APEX_JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/APEX_JSON.htm#AEAPI29635)
2. [WRITE Procedure Signature
   15](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/WRITE-Procedure-Signature-15.htm#AEAPI29857)
3. [Same question at Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/message/15469497)